# Can grunt install its own plugins?

Tags: gruntjs, npm

It seems like if want to runt grunt on a "clean" machine we must write an external script that runs "npm install" first.

Is there a way to make grunt run first "npm install" to install its plugins in devDependencies?

Comment: Why don't you simply run `grunt install` yourself?

Comment: @jgillich what would that do?

Comment: Oh sorry typo, I meant `npm install`.

Comment: As i said it means i need to wrap it with some shell file

Comment: Yep but can't you run npm in that shell file? The thing is that grunt requires at least the `grunt` package or it won't even run.

Answer (score 1):

Grunt is just a node module and like any other module it's uses npm for dependency management. As I know, npm itself can not be accessed programmatically from modules.

But your questions can be solved in the grunt-way. Grunt has an interface called [grunt.task.exists](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.exists). You can use it for checking if the tasks were loaded and if something's not, then run [grunt-shell](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-shell)'s task containing `npm install`. One of the ways to implement this is to dynamically create aliases:

```
function safeTasks(tasks) {
  exists: for (var task in config) {
    if (!grunt.task.exists(task)) {
      tasks.unshift('shell:dependencies');
      break exists;
    }
  }

  return tasks;
}

grunt.registerTask('default', safeTasks(['one', 'another']));
```

Where `config` is the object passed to `grunt.initConfig()`.